# Maven Compiled files list

Tags: maven

Do we have anyway to list all the files with their file name and location, compiled by maven, when we execute mvn compile.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In debug mode maven will print this information.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I am pretty new to maven. Could you please let me know how can i enable debug mode in maven.